# 8085 Simulator Misbehaving

Tags: assembly, 8085

I'm writing a simple assembly program. And has written upto this.

Now the code looks fine. But it gives me this error

[image]

ps: I think something of my installation is gone wrong. Please help

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm.  But why did i have to add 0 there. please explain

Comment: The second error message answers your question.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez please add your comment as answer. So i could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "0" before "AABBH" and "CCDDH".

When a hexadecimal number starts with a letter, it might be confused with a word. For example, you may have a variable named "AABBH", which is a valid name. To avoid this confussion, just add 0 before hexadecimal numbers when they start with a letter.